# How do I initialize a class instance with user input and calculated input?

Tags: java, class, initialization

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to initialize an instance of a class with user entered data and program calculated data.

I am asking the user for a few things, a name and some numbers. Then supposed to call a class to store those numbers and output various results. So i have to do a few calculations with the information the user enters, then pass all of that into my class so that I can output the information the user gave me as well as my calculations from the class.

How do I do this?

Edit: Sorry, forgot the details. I am using Java, and I am not sure what code examples I could list that would be short. let me try these. The first is my constructor for my class..

```
    public Employee(String empName, double hourlyRate, double regHours, 
                    double grossPay, double regPay, double netPay, 
                    double taxes, double otHours, double otPay, 
                    double totHours)
    {
```

This is my attempt to call the instance of the class....

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee(empName, hourlyRate, regHours, grossPay, 
                                   regPay, netPay, taxes, otHours, otPay, 
                                   totHours);
```

Comment: are you talking about Object oriented programming?

Comment: Have you looked into [constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming))?

Comment: First of all, welcome to this forum! Second: What language and platform do you want to use? And third... what you ask for is unfortunately just the very basic syntax for using classes... you have to show some attempts (meaning: code) to get some help.

Comment: I have edited my OP with some more details, sorry for that :(

Comment: It may just be me, but I have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you clarify your question? (possibly in the form of a short example)

Answer (score 0):

Its just OOP. define some variables within the class to store your passed value as well as your calculations.

define getter methods  for what you want to get.